# If else condition statements not working correctly in java

Tags: java

I actually implement a simple program. but following code segment not functioning as i want.

```
if((charAtIndexTwo !='A') || (charAtIndexTwo !='E') || (charAtIndexTwo !='I') || (charAtIndexTwo !='O') || (charAtIndexTwo !='U') || (charAtIndexTwo !='Y')) {
        System.out.println((charAtIndexTwo!='A'));
        if((totalOne%2 ==0) && (totalTwo%2==0) && (totalThree%2==0) && (totalFour%2==0)) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
```

If I run the program with  the `charAtIndexTwo = A`, **Console prints false** . It cannot happen. I think, because in the first if segment I check whether the `charAtIndexTwo` equal to A or not. As it is A, how program prints false rather than jumping to else segment? Can anyone suggest me why is that?

Comment: Your first condition will always be true.. Did you intend to use `&&`?

Comment: That first condition is not useful. `charAtIndexTwo` cannot have more than one value at the same time, so at least one of the options has to be true, making the overall condition true.

Comment: If `charAtIndexTwo == 'A'`, then I would expect your first `println()` statement to output `false` to the console. Wouldn't you?

Comment: No. if charAtIndexTwo == 'A' how it comes to first println()

Comment: @user7 if charAtIndexTwo == 'A' how first condition become true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((charAtIndexTwo !='A') || (charAtIndexTwo !='E') || (charAtIndexTwo !='I') || 
(charAtIndexTwo !='O') || (charAtIndexTwo !='U') || (charAtIndexTwo !='Y'))
```

On this line you're evaluating with OR condition which means if any one of the condition is True then the program will jump into If.

When charAtIndexTwo = A then

```
(charAtIndexTwo !='A') = False || (charAtIndexTwo !='E') = True 
// this is where it enters the If Condition
```

***Solution : Replace all OR || with AND &&***

Comment: Thanks. i understand the concept here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your OR (||) condition.
(charAtIndexTwo !='A') || (charAtIndexTwo !='E')
Now the first portion is definitely false and it should jump to else but the OR (||) condition makes it to check (charAtIndexTwo !='E') which is TRUE. So instead of going to else, it comes into the if condition and prints FALSE (which itself is correct)

You just need to tweak your IF condition logic

```
 if((charAtIndexTwo=='A')||(charAtIndexTwo=='E')||(charAtIndexTwo=='I')||(charAtIndexTwo=='O')||(charAtIndexTwo=='U')||(charAtIndexTwo=='Y'))

{
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}else
{
    System.out.println((charAtIndexTwo != 'A'));
    if ((totalOne % 2 == 0) && (totalTwo % 2 == 0) && (totalThree % 2 == 0) && (totalFour % 2 == 0)) {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: So that means i have to replace || with the && ryt?

Comment: Most probably YES.
I am not sure about your requirement.